# Breadth first search - confusion

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

To understand breadth first search I watched numerous videos. I then found the python code on [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/)

I noticed however that when I removed the line
`g.addEdge(2, 0)` from the code, the outputs were limited to `2, 3`

Is this correct or should the BFS method traverse upwards too and therefore find nodes 0 and 1? If so, would I be correct in thinking the `defaultdict` method isn't ideal for BFS?

This is the code from GeeksForGeeks

```
from collections import defaultdict 

class Graph: 
    def __init__(self):  
        self.graph = defaultdict(list) 

    def addEdge(self,u,v): 
        self.graph[u].append(v) 

    def BFS(self, s): 
        visited = [False] * (len(self.graph)) 
        queue = [] 
        queue.append(s) 
        visited[s] = True

        while queue: 
            s = queue.pop(0) 
            print (s, end = " ") 
            for i in self.graph[s]: 
                if visited[i] == False: 
                    queue.append(i) 
                    visited[i] = True
g = Graph() 
g.addEdge(0, 1) 
g.addEdge(0, 2) 
g.addEdge(1, 2) 
g.addEdge(2, 0)
g.addEdge(2, 3) 
g.addEdge(3, 3) 
g.BFS(2)
```

Comment: This is a directed graph, that's why when you remove the edge from `2` to `0`, It no longer prints `0` or it's neighbor `1`.

Comment: You have a directed graph there. If you remove (2 -> 0), then yes, starting at 2, you can only get to 3.

Comment: It is correct - without (2, 0) edge there is no way from edges 2 and 3 to edges 0 or 1.